# Using callbacks with Socket IO

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using node and socket io to stream twitter feed to the browser, but the stream is too fast. In order to slow it down, I'm attempting to use setInterval, but it either only delays the start of the stream (without setting evenly spaced intervals between the tweets) or says that I can't use callbacks when broadcasting. Server side code below:

```
function start(){

stream.on('tweet', function(tweet){

if(tweet.coordinates && tweet.coordinates != null){
    io.sockets.emit('stream', tweet);
    }       

});
}

  io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
   console.log('connected');    

   setInterval(start, 4000);

    });
```

Comment: Your start function is attaching a listener to the stream. Once the listener is attached, the socket will emit events as fast as its receiving them. To space out your emit() calls, you need to create some sort of queue, or by pausing and resuming your stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how `.on()` works for streams.  It's an event handler.  Once it is installed, it's there and the stream can call you at any time.  Your interval is actually just making things worse because it's installing multiple `.on()` handlers.

It's unclear what you mean by "data coming too fast".  Too fast for what?  If it's just faster than you want to display it, then you can just store the tweets in an array and then use timers to decide when to display things from the array.

If data from a stream is coming too quickly to even store and this is a flowing nodejs stream, then you can pause the stream with the `.pause()` method and then, when you're able to go again, you can call `.resume()`.   See http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause for more info.